# Correct conversion from synchronous to async controller methods (when using void)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0 Web API controllers I am trying to rewrite them from synchronous to asynchronous methods.

This actually works easy for my controller methods just querying data.

Unfortunatly I wrapped the DbContext method SaveChanges into some helper methods for centralized logging of DB changes.

And here I start struggling how to correctly use combinations of void in an asynchronous context.

Explanation of the code: 
MyController is a web api controller. The PostMethod is a (currently) synchronous post method receiving the request model, handling it, making changes and then saving the changes.

The SaveChangesWithLogs within the controller calls the extension method and prints the returned logs.

The extension method SaveChangesWithLogs generates the log entries (some before saving, some after saving), does the actual saving and returns the logs.

```
  public class MyController : BaseController 
  {

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostMethod([FromBody]PostRequestModel request)
    {
        //do something
        SaveChangesWithLogs();
        //return created at
    }

    protected void SaveChangesWithLogs()
    {
      List logs = DbContext.SaveChangesWithLogs();
      foreach (string log in logs)
      {
        LogInfo(log); //just prints the generated logs
      }
    }

  }

  public static class MyExtensionMethod 
  {

    public static List SaveChangesWithLogs(this DbContext dbContext)
    {
      List logs = null;
      //pre-save prepare logs
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
      //post-save modifications of logs
      return logs;
    }
  }
```

In tutorials about async programming they mention the methods should be async all the way down.

**So my question:** How would the (method signatures) of the SaveChangesWithLogs methods look like?

```
  public class MyController2 : BaseController 
  {

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task PostMethod([FromBody]PostRequestModel request)
    {
        //do something
        await SaveChangesWithLogs();
        //return created at
    }

    //does a correct implementation need async here too?
    protected void SaveChangesWithLogs()
    {
      List logs = await DbContext.SaveChangesWithLogs();
      foreach (string log in logs)
      {
        LogInfo(log); //just prints the generated logs
      }

      //return what???
    }

  }

  public static class MyExtensionMethod2 
  {

    public static async Task> SaveChangesWithLogs(this DbContext dbContext)
    {
      List logs = null;
      //pre-save prepare logs
      await dbContext.SaveChanges();
      //post-save modifications of logs
      return logs;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What was `void` becomes `async Task` (no need to return anything from that method). What has return value of `SomeType` becomes `async Task<SomeType>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the return type as before and wrap Task around it. There is no more magic than that involved.

I'm guessing that your List type is of some type and added that for display purposes.

```
protected async Task<bool> SaveChangesWithLogs()
    {
      List logs = await DbContext.SaveChangesWithLogs();
      foreach (string log in logs)
      {
        LogInfo(log); //just prints the generated logs
      }      
      return true;
    }

public static async Task<List<myLogType>> SaveChangesWithLogs(this DbContext dbContext)
{
    List<myLogType> logs = null;
    //pre-save prepare logs
    await dbContext.SaveChanges();
    //post-save modifications of logs
    return logs;
}
```

Comment: So that the SaveChangesWithLogs in the controller is not using async isn't a problem? This was one of the things I was most unsure about.

Comment: Updated my answer. I always use Task<bool> in void functions that are being updated to async pattern.

Comment: But it does not make sense to use Task<bool> and always return true. Just use Task as return value.

Comment: That is completely true :) but then we get into async error handling and what strategies you want to implement there. The bool is the minimum for signalling that the the operation failed.

Comment: In language with exceptions, like C#, you throw exception when something failed, not return false. Besides, why then method originally returned void, but after convertion to async started returning boolean?